# Малый контраст фона изменённых вопросов в избранном

Tags: предложение, избранное

Когда произошло какое-либо событие в одном из вопросов избранного, то такие вопросы помечаются фоном, однако этот фон слишком уж светлый. По крайней мере на моём мониторе при обычном угле зрения его практически не видно: приходится изменять угол зрения, чтобы его отличить:

[image]

Comment: Вполне нормальный

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вашего монитора серьёзные проблемы с передачей цветов (низкий порог белого?), потому что на моём мониторе контраст достаточно сильный. Попробуйте откалибровать монитор.

Если не помогло, то можете добавить пользовательский стиль:

```css
.user-show-new .highlight-row {
    background-color: #eea;
}
```

Ну или вообще:

```css
.user-show-new .highlight-row {
    background-color: #000;
}
.user-show-new .highlight-row .views,
.user-show-new .highlight-row .votes,
.user-show-new .highlight-row .mini-counts,
.user-show-new .highlight-row .question-hyperlink,
.user-show-new .highlight-row .answer-hyperlink{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Правда такой стиль более хрупкий, конечно.